# Feasibility of a project in certain languages

Tags: platform

My current project is a very simple browser-based game. The player moves with the keys and draws a bow with the mouse to shoot arrows at approaching enemies. This seemed to me like the perfect game for a Python/PyGame implementation and it proved to be true - except if I want it browser-based (Desktop version already works perfectly).

Is there any way I can get Python/PyGame running from a server in a browser window? I tried Kivy but it seems to have problems handling PyGame.

Is there a way to use HTML, PHP or the like to get the Python/PyGame script running in a browser window by "translating" inputs to the Python script and vice versa translating returns into view changes?

Is there an alternative (JavaScript + additional libraries?) that offers me: PNG with Alpha handling readily implemented (I don't really want to use another few days to write that on my own...), easy catching of mouse/key inputs and an "easy-going" license policy that allows me to publish it donation-based without having to pay for a license?

*Note: If I really have to change to another language anyway, then I'd prefer one where I can implement catching touch-screen inputs from mobile devices.*

I'd really appreciate any advice on these questions as I'm really stuck with it until I know to which language I have to translate the Python/PyGame version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use Python in browser like you want.

But you can sure use Javascript for your needs.

I've made an experiment back to when I was still in school.

Check the source code, it should help you to reach your goal.

The game works in pure Javascript and CSS, no canvas, no library besides jQuery, you need to use the arrows to move, there was a Ajax functionnality I stripped of, so you can run it as is from the html file.

http://dl.free.fr/fxByZo3hd

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer I have been looking for.